# How to return a null if the query doesn't find a row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2017. I am creating the whole MySQL Sakila database into mine in Azure Data Studio. I am currently stuck with functions, specifically with the line:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND RETURN NULL;
```

This is my attempt, without the line that I mention it seems that the query has no errors.

```
CREATE FUNCTION inventory_held_by_customer (@p_inventory_id INT)
RETURNS int
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @v_customer_id INT;
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND RETURN NULL; ---if the query finds no rows at all, then return a null
  SELECT @v_customer_id=customer_id
  FROM rental
  WHERE return_date IS NULL
  AND inventory_id = @p_inventory_id;

  RETURN(@v_customer_id);
END;
```

This is the original query for MySQL

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `inventory_held_by_customer`(p_inventory_id INT) RETURNS int(11)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_customer_id INT;
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND RETURN NULL;

  SELECT customer_id INTO v_customer_id
  FROM rental
  WHERE return_date IS NULL
  AND inventory_id = p_inventory_id;

  RETURN v_customer_id;
END
```

Thanks in advance, I appreciate the help!

Comment: In SQL Server null will automatically be returned if no result is found. However you have a flaw, you are returning a single scalar value, which you are selecting from a table. However what if the `select` returns multiple rows? You will be returning 1 random value.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dale for showing me that there's a flaw on the query. Would that be fixed if I returned a Table instead of an INT? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Only you know what the function is attempting to achieve and how it will be used. Do you wish to return a single value? Or a table of values?

Comment: `EXIT HANDLER` is MySql syntax, not SQL Server

Comment: @Stu OP is trying to convert from MySQL to SQL Server.

Comment: How are you intending to consume the output of the function? A table-valued function would seem to be more approprate perhaps, ie, return a list of qualifying IDs?

Comment: Well basically I should input the inventory_id and it will show the customer_id that has that inventory. So for now it should be a scalar value, tbh I haven't experimented with creating aggregating functions yet.

Comment: I guess you have other mechanisms to ensure that a particular inventory item is only on one un-returned rental at a time, so in that case your function should work as is (well once you remove the `DECLARE EXIT HANDLER...` line which isn't required. Really though, why didn't you just test a couple of scenarios without that line - you would have seen that it worked - and saved you all the time to ask a question?

Comment: I guess you are right, for the next time I will run different scenarios to test it beforehand. I just got a lil overwhelmed, still I learned a lot from what you and @Stu commented, and for that I thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you do not need to add `DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND RETURN NULL;` to your function, it will return null if there is no result anyway.

Secondly, scalar functions are slow, because they are executed in a separate context on every single row. It is much more performant to create an inline TVF instead:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION inventory_held_by_customer (@p_inventory_id INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
  SELECT customer_id
  FROM rental
  WHERE return_date IS NULL
  AND inventory_id = @p_inventory_id
);

GO
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the advice and information! The function looks a lot cleaner too. After what Dale commented I tried to use RETURNS TABLE without success but you helped me to pinpoint where I made the mistake. Thank you a lot, I appreciate it!

Comment: @Kaelan - Note: That is the SQL-Server version.  Do you also need MySQL?